# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel 7.30.4

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hello i am doing a small apply coupon input that will. i am getting the following error  [HTTP/2 405 Method Not Allowed ]"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD"

Html part where you applied the coupon

```
  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="promo_code">Apply Promocode:</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coupon_code" placeholder="Apply Promocode" name="coupon_code">
                                      <b><span id="message" style="color:green;"></span></b>
                                    </div>
```

```
The js for the ajax part

        if($('#promo_code').val()!=''){
     
            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{ route('user.apply.coupon') }}",
                        data:{
                            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                            coupon_code: $('#coupon_code').val()
                        },
                        success: function(dataResult){
                            var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                            if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                                var after_apply=$('#total_price').val()-dataResult.value;
                                $('#total_price').val(after_apply);
                                $('#apply').hide();
                                $('#edit').show();
                                $('#message').html("Promocode applied successfully !");
                                
                            }
                            else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                                $('#message').html("Invalid promocode !");
                            }
                        }
            });
        }
```

The line i have added to the routes (routes/web.php)

```
    //apply coupon
    Route::post('apply-coupon', 'CardController@applyCoupon')->name('apply.coupon');
```

The CARD Controller part

```
class CardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
public function applyCoupon(Request $request)
    {
     echo "test";   
    }

}
```

What am i missing?  I am quite new with laravel

Comment: It looks like the route name is `apply.coupon` and not `user.apply.coupon`.

Comment: you perhaps have some route that matches before this one and takes 'apply-coupon' as a parameter.

Comment: @pmcpimentel i tried apply.coupon also but still same error.

Comment: @Snapey no there is no route i have searched the whole code

Comment: You perhaps misunderstand.  I mean a route that has a parameter like user/{profile} that if it comes before user/apply-coupon then the profile route will be matched

Comment: Run the `artisan optimize:clear` command to clear all framework cache and try again. There is no way it returns `405` on a route that shouldn't exist (`users.apply.coupon`).

Comment: @pmcpimentel you can't possibly tell that the route is not inside a namespaced route group